# SASS Error : Invalid CSS after " expected pseudoclass or pseudoelement "

Tags: css, sass

I am trying something new today.. SASS is all new for me. Can anyone please tell me what cause this error?

```
/*
Error: Invalid CSS after "    margin:": expected pseudoclass or pseudoelement, was "0px"
        on line 5 of /Users/kishorechandra/S-ERP/sass/styles.scss

1: @import "compass";
2: @import "partials/variables";
3: 
4: .ui.menu
5:     margin:0px
6:     background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)
7:     font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif
8: 
9: .ui.icon.menu .active.item
10:     color: #FFB300

Backtrace:
/Users/kishorechandra/S-ERP/sass/styles.scss:5
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use space after property: , then the compiler won't get confused anymore. so replace `margin:0px` with `margin: 0px`. And have fun learning Sass.

Comment: what a lifesaver, I was going mad haha!

Answer (score 9):

Which SASS-Sytnax are you using, Sass (without curly braces) or SCSS (with curly braces, more css-like looking)?

The Compiler interpretes "margin:" as element (`<margin></margin>`) because after the colon is no space and thefor tries to handle it as state (like :hover, :active) or pseudoelement (::after, ::before).

Either switch to the SCSS favour, or just add an space aftre the colon.

I prefer the SCSS syntax, because most others use it and it's less error-prone than the classic Sass.

Comment: If you're using Angular CLI you can setup the desired extension when you create your project, or modify it later in `angular.json`. https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-sass-with-the-angular-cli - looks like I selected `sass` when I really wanted `scss` :-)

Answer (score 1):

Came across the same problem while working on a React project. Solved the problem by fixing the filename of SASS file from `file_name.sass` to `file_name.scss`.

Thus, make sure the SASS file has the extension of `.scss`.