# Angular 9 Production build Error - Expected a pseudo-class or pseudo-element

Tags: angular

Angular9 Project, ng serve is working fine but when I do production build the following error:

> chunk {} runtime.5d6d7c5bcca533f7263c.js (runtime) 1.46 kB [entry]
>   [rendered] chunk {1} main.d2b72f349c71c888a662.js (main) 128 bytes
>   [initial] [rendered] chunk {2} polyfills.283e8bcde8bca38df4ea.js
>   (polyfills) 130 bytes [initial] [rendered] chunk {3}
>   polyfills-es5.47231a2d33c3f2286472.js (polyfills-es5) 83.1 kB
>   [initial] [rendered] chunk {4} styles.c5b7147fccf47beb83b4.js (styles)
>   483 kB [initial] [rendered] chunk {scripts}
>   scripts.6786fa7c6c013a08a688.js (scripts) 808 kB [entry] [rendered]
>   Date: 2020-03-02T20:18:43.460Z - Hash: 266c3c73c2b8a9576a9b - Time:
>   64655ms

**ERROR in Expected a pseudo-class or pseudo-element.**

Need help in finding the reason.

Comment: You can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41197303/sass-error-invalid-css-after-expected-pseudoclass-or-pseudoelement

Comment: Project is around 1000 screen really difficult to visit and change each property, Is there better way to solve. It was working up to angular 8. In version 9 I am facing the issue.

Comment: do you use /deep/ ?

Comment: No, used all imports    @import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

Comment: You use CSS throughout the project ? or also scss ?

Comment: We used only css

Comment: Sorry, I saw there are few scss files as well

Comment: could you try to import bootstrap like that @import "node_modules/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"; (path to adapt if needed, depends on your node modules) , may be it's the ~ which is problematic   and try to rebuild node-sass (npm rebuild node-sass)

Comment: @LakshmanMiani how did you solve this? I am facing this error too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65183286/angular-11-production-build-error-expected-a-pseudo-class-or-pseudo-element

Answer (score 0):

My solution was:

1. Manually "apply" the fix from this PR https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/19568/files to this file

> node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\optimize-css-webpack-plugin.js line 69

2. Now, the error message should display the actual file where the error appeared

In my case i had somehow an invalid? character in a simple stylus rule

```
.formfield
    padding-left 0
    padding-right 10px
    width 100%
```

I had to replace all whitespaces infront of the "width 100%". I was only able to find this by removing styles from my file until i found the one causing this error.

I hope that this will help someone, even if the post is already a few years old.