# Angular 9 Build error Expected a pseudo-class or pseudo-element

Tags: angular, optimization, stylus, angular9, terser

After I upgraded my Angular solution from 8 to 9, build now fails when the optimization option of angular.json is set to true. I observed the terminal and found that it fails on the terser plugin part of the optimization process. I am now quite sure that the cause of the error is somewhere on our stylesheet.

Here are what I have fixed so far :

- Removed :ng-deep and /deep/
- Fixed css properties by adding space after colons ':'

Are there other things that I need to check so that the minification process proceeds? Also we are using stylus.

A question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60489092/angular-9-production-build-error-expected-a-pseudo-class-or-pseudo-element). I still can't add a comment and the question has no recent activities so I posted my own.

Answer (score 1):

Russian:
У меня была похожая ситуация. Удалять :ng-deep и /deep/ не нужно! 
У меня в одном css файле была ошибка `: host ::ng-deep`. Те между двоеточием и ключевым словом host был пробел. После удаления пробела `:host` проект нормально собрался.

English:
I had a similar situation. Delete :ng-deep and /deep/ no need!

I had a bug in one css file: `host ::ng-deep`. Those between the colon and the host keyword had a space or gap. After removing the space: `:host` the project is completed the build.

Comment: Please post your answer in English.

Comment: Google translate gives this:

"I had a similar situation. Delete: ng-deep and / deep / is not necessary! I had an error in one css file : host ::ng-deep. Those between the colon and the host keyword were a space. After deleting the gap, the :host project was properly assembled."

Seems like a proper translation. Tough solution but just check for any formatting errors in your css/scss files pretty much. Sucks if you have tons to go through.